# Force bootstrap row to take entire heigh of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a django project that I am working on and I am integrating bootstrap into my html files. Within my html template, I have a row that is only as big as the content inside of the row is. I want to make it take the entire height of the page and completely fill the page. I tried standard css and it is not working at all. Is there a way to force it. Another question I have is if there is a way for me to fix the position of a row so that it does not move when I scroll up and down.

I want the first row to be fixed

the two side columns in second row to take the rest of the screen.

Here is the html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block standard %}
<div class="row">
  <div class=" border-padding solid-borders">
    <a href="{% url 'user_groups' %}">
      <img src="{% static 'images/Yap-Logo-6.png'%}" class="header-icon-size" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
    ...
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
  <div class="border-padding solid-borders">
    <a href="">
      <img src="{% static 'images/user.png'%}" class="header-icon-size" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 content-backgroun">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 content-backgroun">
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `height: 100vh` to an element will make it's height 100% of the viewport's height.

To fix an element to the a page, use `position: fixed` to "stick" it to the page, the use `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` properties to position the element where you would like it to go.

There are a lot of nuances to how the rest of your CSS is written, but generally speaking, `position: fixed` will stick elements to the page and using `vh` units will allow you to adjust the height of elements based upon how tall the user's viewport is.

Quick examples below:

```css
.row-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: salmon;
}
.row-tall {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, lightgreen, lightyellow);
}
.row {
  padding: 2em 5%;
}
body {
  margin: 6em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-tall">
  <h1>This row is 100% of the viewport's height.</h1>  
</div>

<div class="row row-tall">
  <h2>This row is <i>also</i> 100% of the viewport's height and is only here to fill vertical space.</h2>  
</div>

<div class="row row-fixed">
  <p>This is fixed to the top</p>
</div>
```